# Looking for a search string in a file and printing next word in that line

Tags: tcl

for example, consider a file "abc.txt" has following content

```
{apple_Text "1"}

{banana_Text "2"}

{orange_Text "3"}
```

Now, I want to search "apple_Text" keyword in that file and if found it should print second column value in that, i.e. "1". Can I know how to do that in Tcl??

Comment: Do you have any code written yet?

Comment: i ve code in python..i know python than tcl..

Comment: Are there blank lines between those lines with text? Are they separate versions of the file, or what? (Just trying to understand __exactly__ what the input is.)

Comment: If you need help getting the text to display properly, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help -- typically indenting by 4 spaces will do it
.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

```
set f [open abc.txt]
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {apple_Text\s+"(.*)"} $line all value]} {
        puts $value
    }
}
close $f
```

Basically, I search each line for "apple_Text" and extract the value from the line.

Answer (score 2):

Here a sweet short solution:

```
set fd [open abc.txt r]
set data [read $fd]
close $fd
puts [lindex [lsearch -inline -index 0 -inline $data "apple_Text"] 1]
```

This will only find the first result through.

I consider the input as a valid Tcl list of Tcl lists. (`{apple_Text "1"}` is a Tcl list with 1 element: `apple_Text "1"`, which is itself a valid Tcl list with 2 elements: `apple_Text` and `1`)
If this does not match your input, then things are a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

```
set fp [open "abc.txt" r]
set filecontent [read $fp]
set input_list [split $filecontent "\n"]
set appleTextList [lsearch -all -inline $input_list "apple_Text*"]
foreach elem $appleTextList {
    puts "[lindex $elem 1]"
}
close $fp
```