# Search for a string in a text file, and output the line after the string searched for

Tags: tcl

I am looking for a solution for searching a text file for a string let's say "Hello" and each time it finds "Hello" in the text file, it skips to the next line and prints that entire line into a new text file

example Text file contents:

```
Hello
password:xxxxx user:xxxxx
Foo
password:xxxx user:xxxxxx
Foo
password:xxxxx user:xxxxx
Hello
password:xxxxx user:xxxxx
Foo
password:xxxx user:xxxx
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711643/looking-for-a-search-string-in-a-file-and-printing-next-word-in-that-line

Comment: Are you searching for Hello anywhere in the line, or should the entire line be equal to Hello?

Comment: I'll refer you to the [Tcl manual pages](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm), read particularly `open`, `close` and `gets`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  if {[string match $::StringToFind $line]} {
  continue
 }
```